# How do I return a number which has a prefix from a statement

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I return a number which has a prefix from a statement.

My string is as follows "This is a test104 in JavaScript".

I would like to return 'test104' from the above statement. The string can actually appear anywhere in the statement and also the preceding numbers could change, so 'test223' or 'test335'.

I would really appreciate some help here. I find regular expressions warps my mind.

Thank you.

Comment: This is the most basic use of a regex, you should try to figure yourself how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should have really started from reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
Anyway, the following code should get you going:

```
"This is a test104 in JavaScript".match(/test\d+/g) // ["test104"]
```

Expression `test\d+` matches any string starting with "test", followed by any number of digits.